# What todo when composer update and composer install give error ?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I run `composer install` I got this error, telling me to use `composer update`

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.3.0].
    - doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for symfony/css-selector v4.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v4.0.3].
    - symfony/css-selector v4.0.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher v4.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.0.3].
    - symfony/event-dispatcher v4.0.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/instantiator[1.1.0].
    - doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.32 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.3.0].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.5.32 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.32].
```

I run `composer update`, I got this

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/dbal v2.6.3 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/dbal v2.6.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/dbal v2.6.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/dbal v2.6.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for doctrine/dbal ^2.6 -> satisfiable by doctrine/dbal[v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.6.3].
```

Now what should I do ?

This is what I have in `composer.json`

**cat composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "anouar/paypalpayment": ">=3.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.6",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "spatie/laravel-newsletter": "^4.1",
        "srmklive/paypal": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": ["app/Http/Helper.php"]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to read the error message? `doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.`

Comment: What is the quick fix ? adjust the composer.json or update PHP version ?

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: I will try with this `"doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",`

Comment: You cannot change composer.json since it comes from the other package. Either upgrade your php or use older versions of dependencies. And you better **NOT** simply change just one dependency in your code, since the whole `laravel` is tested to work with a particular combination of those. So if you want something older - everything should be older, from the older version of `laravel`.

Comment: I deployed my staging VM fine 3 weeks a go.

Comment: Tonight, I decided to deploy my prod VM. running those 2 commands, I got the error. I don't think I change my package.json in the last a couple weeks.

Comment: I've been running Laravel 5.5 all a long. I don't really do anything.

Comment: Did I overwrite the `composer.lock` ? should I check-in my `composer.lock` ?

Comment: Can someone please explain this issue ? Why am I seeing it ?

Comment: `doctrine/dbal v2.6` requires php7.1. You could not have been running it on php 7.0. You changed something somewhere. "Why am I seeing it ?" --- because you're trying to install packages that require newer php.

Comment: Not true, I disagree.  Both VMs are on PHP 7.0, both VMs have the package.json with `"doctrine/dbal": "^2.6",`

Comment: Explain why my staging was working fine, then ?! here is my staging : http://159.89.178.148/

Comment: See, working as it should .... they both deployed the same way, running same PHP version from DO. They should behave the same. It throw me off they're not behave the same.

Comment: "Not true, I disagree. " --- composer is not agree with you. I'm just saying what I am seeing. "Explain why my staging was working fine, then" --- I really have no idea what you've been changing recently, sorry. You can continue claiming you have not touched anything, the fact is though `"doctrine/dbal": "^2.6"` **CANNOT BE INSTALLED ON php 7.1**.

Comment: *CANNOT BE INSTALLED ON php 7.1*, 3 weeks a go, I can. Look at my staging.

Comment: If I don't want to upgrade my PHP version, or upgrade my Laravel because it is not *SAFE* and longer to do, what option do I have right now ? Please advise, I am not saying you're wrong, but I am not dreaming either, I've done it.

Comment: `doctrine/dbal` dependency on php7.1 was added 8 months ago, before v2.6.0 was released. "Look at my staging" --- I have no idea what you're running there, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue few days ago I fixed it by faking the php version in my composer.json file **[Not recommended]**.

```
"config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "platform" : {
            "php": "7.1"
        }
    }
```

For more details read [this](http://doctrine-project.org/2017/07/25/php-7.1-requirement-and-composer.html)

Or you can execute composer update/install commands with --ignore-platform-reqs flag as shown below

> composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: "faking" PHP version using `platform` setting **is** recommended way - in this way you can ensure that no one in team will install dependencies not compatible with your production server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install them one by one. In Ubuntu you can use apt for it.

For example:

```
sudo apt search inflector
```

You will see a package related to you version of PHP. Then just do normal installation of it via:

```
sudo apt install php-symfony-inflector
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to tackle this, but all of them are highly dependant on the environment you are trying to run the command.

Let's assume that the composer file is from a 3rd piece of code, if they set the minimum php version it is ok to assume they did so for a reason. I would not try and circumvent this error by faking the version or changing the requirements.

If you have access, you could:

1. update the php version on your environment
2. run this in an docker container that has the required versions for your project.
3. install a php-fpm version that will match what the requirement is.

With the update option (1) you have to make sure that any other projects that run on the environment don't have compatibility issues with the version you may be updating to.
The docker option (2) is in my opinion the safest one, but you'll have to do some reading on how to set it up (assuming your runing on linux: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/).
and the last one (3) requires you to setup a php-fpm and then make sure that your virtual host runs with the correct php to make sure you are running on the correct version (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-on-one-server-using-apache-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04)