# Update composer without changing PHP version

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I try to update my composer but i get this error.

```
 Problem 1
- doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
- doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
- doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Installation request for doctrine/instantiator (locked at 1.1.0) -> satisfiable by doctrine/instantiator[1.1.0].
```

[image]

How i can solve this problem without upgrade my version PHP ?

Comment: You can't - it's a requirement...

Comment: If you do not want to upgrade your PHP version the only option is to look for Laravel which runs with your current PHP Version.

Comment: The actual issue is that doctrine/instantiator increased the minimum requirement in a minor release. Laravel runs fine at 7.0 which OP has installed. It is the add-on requesting 7.1. You may be able to cap doctrine/instantiator to use ~1.0. Get the previous minor version. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20255

Comment: This issue is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040427/what-todo-when-composer-update-and-composer-install-give-error/49454037#49454037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to update your php version, just use this..

`composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`

or

`composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

**NOTES**
it is recommended to upgrade your version

Comment: ....and then wait for you application to explode because they might use code that your server cannot compile